# Project runs on first time but when I run it again It shows project has Stopped

Tags: android

As you can tell from this question topic, when Run my program on the emulator it works perfectly on the first time, but when I run it again without any changes, It shows "(Project name) has Stop Working.

I really don't know how to fix this, I tried cleaning the project, building the APK again, but still there is no solution.

any help please, will be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

TextView latitude;
TextView longitude;
TextView accuracy;
TextView altitude;
TextView address;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
    longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
    accuracy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accuracy);
    altitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.altitude);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Check if we already have a location access permission
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // this mean we don't have permissions, so we need to ask for it.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1); // 1 here is some sort of id to identify this request, its called request code


    } else {
        // we do have permission

        // 0 , 0 mean always keep track of user location changes, we can change it to be every 10 seconds or something like that.
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

    }


    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


            latitude.setText("Latitude: " + location.getLatitude());
            longitude.setText("Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
            accuracy.setText("Accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy());
            altitude.setText("Alitiude: " + location.getAltitude());



        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };
}

@Override // this controls the dialog that asks user for location access permission
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    // check if user clicked on the dialog and choose allow.
    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // if we have permission, then update user location. we need this check to make the code run!
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // 0 , 0 mean always keep track of user location changes, we can change it to be every 10 seconds or something like that.
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
      }

   }
}
```

Even when I copy this code and put it in a new project, it works but again, same problem when I run it again it doesnt work.

I got this error

09-10 21:35:37.936 2588-2588/com.example.qubayel.test2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.qubayel.test2, PID: 2588
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.qubayel.test2/com.example.qubayel.test2.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid listener: null
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: probably you didn't stop `locationManager`  add `locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);` in `onDestroy` (override it)

Comment: second time on which line the error is pointing?

Comment: Please Give us the error message. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-monitor.html. Red ones are errors.

Comment: I updated my question with error message thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem was that I'm using locationListener before defining it. on this line of code:

```
 // 0 , 0 mean always keep track of user location changes, we can change it to be every 10 seconds or something like that.
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

This definition should've been on top of my locationListener call:

```
 locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        latitude.setText("Latitude: " + location.getLatitude());
        longitude.setText("Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
        accuracy.setText("Accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy());
        altitude.setText("Alitiude: " + location.getAltitude());



    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
};
```

final code should be like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

TextView latitude;
TextView longitude;
TextView accuracy;
TextView altitude;
TextView address;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
    longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
    accuracy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accuracy);
    altitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.altitude);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


            latitude.setText("Latitude: " + location.getLatitude());
            longitude.setText("Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
            accuracy.setText("Accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy());
            altitude.setText("Alitiude: " + location.getAltitude());



        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

    // Check if we already have a location access permission
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // this mean we don't have permissions, so we need to ask for it.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1); // 1 here is some sort of id to identify this request, its called request code


    } else {
        // we do have permission

        // 0 , 0 mean always keep track of user location changes, we can change it to be every 10 seconds or something like that.
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

    }
}


@Override // this controls the dialog that asks user for location access permission
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    // check if user clicked on the dialog and choose allow.
    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // if we have permission, then update user location. we need this check to make the code run!
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // 0 , 0 mean always keep track of user location changes, we can change it to be every 10 seconds or something like that.
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }

    }
}
```